# division as multiply and LUT ? / fast float division reciprocal

Tags: c++, c, optimization, fpu

Is it possible to make a reciprocal of float division in form 
of look up table (such like 1/f -> 1*inv[f] ) ? How it could be done? 
I think some and mask and shift should be appled to float to make 
it a form of index? How would be it exectly?

Comment: [Are you looking for hackery like this?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root)

Comment: Do you realize that this either loses *a lot* of accuracy, or results in a friggin' **huge** lookup table? There are a lot of floats, even if you restrict yourself to a range like `[0.0, 1.0)`.

Comment: @up I need only reciprocal - say 10 bits of accuracy (1024 floats in look_up table) - I wander if it would be faster or slower

Comment: @H2CO3 no, I need it for division not for inverted square root

Comment: @grungefightr (facepalm truncated) I know, I meant do you want to implement **fast** division using bit-level manipulation or you specifically want to use lookup tables?

Comment: @up want to do fast division reciprocal - but curious what result will it bring to do it in such way lut multiply

Comment: @grungefightr it's possible; I've seen it used in older software rasterizers... though it was all fixed point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can guess an approximate inverse like this:

```
int x = bit_cast<int>(f);
x = 0x7EEEEEEE - x;
float inv = bit_cast<float>(x);
```

In my tests, 0x7EF19D07 was slightly better (tested with the effects of 2 Newton-Raphson refinements included).

Which you can then improve with Newton-Raphson:

```
inv = inv * (2 - inv * f);
```

Iterate as often as you want. 2 or 3 iterations give nice results.

### Better Initial Approximations

To minimize the relative error:

- 0x7EF311C2 (without refinement)
- 0x7EF311C3 (1 refinement)
- 0x7EF312AC (2 refinements)
- 0x7EEEEBB3 (3 refinements)

To minimize the absolute error for inputs between 1 and 2 (they work well enough outside that range, but they may not be the best):

- 0x7EF504F3 (without refinement)
- 0x7EF40D2F (1 refinement)
- 0x7EF39252 (2 refinements)

For three refinement steps, the initial approximation barely affects the maximum relative error. 0x7EEEEEEE works great, and I couldn't find anything better.

Comment: @grungefightr works on my pc ;) But, more seriously, it works by negating the exponent, and the thing it does with the mantissa (or significant) I don't really understand.. but it works out alright somehow.

Comment: Well It works. It is funny, https://dl.dropbox.com/u/42887985/reciprocal_div.jpg <- (pic is ugly but funny and not so big distortion to walls) here I changed division by yrs recpirocal_div, in function that counts distance to walls (without Newt-rpahson ) It works very well, much tnx for this

Comment: could you please attach a complete working example for that cast ? Aren't you supposed to use pointers with a `reinterpret_cast` ?

Comment: @user2485710 `*reinterpret_cast<int*>(&f)` then?

Comment: @harold yes, I know, I was interested in your single and specific example, can you expand a little more providing a working example ?

Comment: @user2485710 I don't really know what you mean

Comment: @harold I can't believe that :), anyway how you are supposing to declare `f` in this example ?

Comment: @user2485710 it should be of type float, it's the input

Comment: Use a union to view the raw bytes of the float as an unsigned integer (represented by variable i), then simply do `i=(0xbe6eb3bfU-i)>>1;` See more. Go to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root).

Answer (score 4):

One method is:

1. Extract the sign, exponent and mantissa from the input
2. Use some of the most significant mantissa bits to look up its reciprocal in a table
3. Negate the exponent, and adjust for the change of scale of the mantissa
4. Recombine the sign, exponent and mantissa to form the output

In step 2, you'll need to choose the number of bits to use, trading between accuracy and table size. You could obtain more accuracy by using the less significant bits to interpolate between table entries.

In step 3, the adjustment is necessary because the input mantissa was in the range (0.5, 1.0], and so its reciprocal is in the range [1.0, 2.0), which needs renormalising to give the output mantissa.

I won't try to write the code for this, since there are probably some slightly fiddly edge cases that I'd miss.

You should also investigate methods involving numerical calculations, which might give better results if memory access is slow; on a modern PC architecture, a cache miss might be as expensive as dozens of arithmetic operations. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28digital%29) looks like a good starting point. And of course, whatever you do, measure it to make sure it is actually faster than an FPU division operation.

Comment: You know I think I only need to MAP some binary part of float (which contains most significant bits) and use such bits (say ten) to use it as an index in look up table - no need of ordered index, converting and calculating - I know i shoul look up in float format spec : >

Comment: @grungefightr: Yes, that's what stage 2 does, but you also need to calculate the new exponent.

Comment: damn exponent, it takes bits, ye - forgot about that   :(

Comment: will rethink it (and accept the answer l8er then if no one gives maybe some bit of useful code example in meantime) :/ At least I could try to use it in specific division cases where I know range of the floats I subdivide by...:/ Will try it

Answer (score 1):

If your minimum step is something like  0.01 then you can support inverse-f from a table. Each index is multiplied by 100 so you can have

```
table[1]----->1.0/0.01
table[3]----->1.0/0.03
table[105]--->1.0/1.05
...
table[10000]->1.0/100.0


10000 elements for a range of (0.00,100.00)
```

If you want better precision, you will need more ram.

Another example:

```
range................: 0.000 - 1000.000
minimum increments ..: 0.001
total element number.: 1 million

something like this: table[2343]=1.0/2.343
```

Another example:

```
range................: 0.000000 - 1.000000
minimum increments ..: 0.000001
total element number.: 1 million

something like this: table[999999]=1.0/0.999999
```

Comment: It is somewhat helpfull but I do not want to translate floats to integers I need a look-up table indexed by somewhat shifted and masked float

Comment: You are right, shifting could be faster than multiplication.  But you cant use a float for indexing of primitives